# jquery paste into input - buggy if done more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using something like this to capture something pasted into an input box.

```
$(".inputTextArea").bind('paste', function(e) {
        var el = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            var text = $(el).val();
        alert(text);
        }, 100);
});
```

This works fine, however if i copy some other text, delete the contents of the field and paste the new copied text then it just shows the previously pasted text.

how can i fix this?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in Chrome 17: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/HtGdR/

Comment: works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/utYxC/

Comment: Some other function on the page updating the value perhaps?

Comment: How about if you highlight the text then hit paste over the highlighted text?

Comment: ok i've tried on another pc...and it works. think there is somthing on my machine affecting this

Comment: @raklos  your code will always get only the whole text from textarea. the one I wrote gets the pasted part.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this http://jsfiddle.net/wdbbv/

```
$(".inputTextArea").bind('paste', function(e) {
        var el = $(this), range = getSelectionRange(el.get(0)); 
        setTimeout(function() {
            var text = el.val().substr(range[0], el.val().length - range[1] 
                                                                 - range[0]);
            alert(text);
        }, 100);
});

function getSelectionRange(el) {
    if ('selectionStart' in el) {
        return [el.selectionStart, el.value.length - el.selectionEnd];          
    } else if (document.selection) {
        var range = document.selection.createRange(), 
            stored_range = range.duplicate();
        stored_range.moveToElementText(el);
        stored_range.setEndPoint('EndToEnd', range);
        return [stored_range.text.length - range.text.length, 
                el.value.length - (el.selectionStart + range.text.length)];
    }
    return null; // modify it any way for unsupported browsers
}​
```

Or you can try to implement the method described here http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/09a3527707d22be0
It uses direct interaction with the clipboard.